# TestDbSet Returning Null Even Though Expectation Set

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to write some unit tests for a piece of logic which uses DbContext. 
In my unit tests, I mock the dbContext and set the expectations.
At one place my code looks like this:

```
var myVar= await dbContext.Set<MyModel>().Where(.. some conditions..).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

I am mocking this dbContext and setting up as follows:

```
var myModelVar = new MyModel();

myModelVar.Id = Guid.NewGuid();



var myModelDbSet = new TestDbSet<MyModel>();

myModelDbSet .Add(myModelVar );

mockDbContext.Setup(dbContext => dbContext.Set<MyModel>()).Returns(myModelDbSet);
```

However, in the above location in the code, the unit test returns null.

Earlier in the code, I set another dbContext expectation which returns correct value in the unit test:

```
var anotherModelVar = new AnotherModel();
    mockDbContext.Setup(dbContext => dbContext.Set<AnotherModel>()
    .FindAsync(It.IsAny<object>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(anotherModelVar ));
```

I receive null value for the TestDbSet expectation and cannot understand the reason why could this be happening?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Instead of mocking DbContext you can test it against "in-memory" database. Check Sqlite "in-memory" feature or if you are using .NET Core "In-Memory provider"